# Add span on selected text in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, range, contenteditable

I want the user to be able to select the text in the div and add the `<span style="color: #ff3300;">` to it.

Example code @ http://jsfiddle.net/SkDA8/1/

Hover over to div and click on the missing picture to display the color-swatch

Thanks for your help!

PS

I want it to work in all modern browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was about to respond to your post to the Rangy group about this, but I'll respond here too.

This is one task that is achievable using `document.execCommand()`:

```
document.execCommand("ForeColor", false, "#ff3300")
```

I've created an update to your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/SkDA8/3/

Comment: It doesn't work when I try it. I've placed you code in the click event. But nothing happens. Am I just being stupid?

Comment: The problem is that when you click the colour swatch, the selection is lost before the `click` event fires. It works if you change it to `mousedown` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly certain what you are trying to do. Here is an updated jsFiddle that gets the value of the colored swatch that is clicked and updates the header color.

http://jsfiddle.net/SkDA8/4/

Hope this helps.

Bob